# Get .pem files in kubernetes with secret certificate

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, yaml, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I have two .pem files, one public and one private, that I want to use in my Rancher kubernetes cluster as a secret.  In the API, I have gone to Resource->Secrets->Certificates and added the certificate with the name `cenc-encryption-certificate`.  In my YAML, I've added the following information

```
  - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
    name: cenc-encryption-certificate
    readOnly: true


volumes:
- name: cenc-encryption-certificate
  secret: 
    defaultMode: 420
    optional: false
    secretName: cenc-encryption-certificate
```

This loads up, but doesn't put the certificate on the file system.  I believe I need a key/path in items, but I don't know what value those should be.  How do I get the .pem files into my container?

Comment: Try doing a `kubectl get secret -o yaml` and ensuring the `data` element does indeed contain two keys with the file contents in base64.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was putting the files out.  It seems that there are two files: `tls.crt` and `tls.key` that get placed.  If you're interested in pulling the keys out themselves, you can use those values as keys to rename them.  Since putting them in /etc/ssl/hosts was also clearing out the directory, the final values I went with were:

```
          - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cenc-encryption-certificate
            name: cenc-encryption-certificate
            readOnly: true


      - name: cenc-encryption-certificate
        secret:
          optional: false
          secretName: cenc-encryption-certificate
          items:
          - key: tls.crt
            path: tls.crt
          - key: tls.key
            path: tls.key
```